# Module not found when requiring library submodule in Jest tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, jestjs, google-cloud-functions

I am currently trying to write some tests for a node-based GCP Cloud Functions application.

At this point I've stripped it down to the bare minimum:

```js
// index.js
const functions = require("@google-cloud/functions-framework");
const testing = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework/testing');


functions.http("updateProvider",
  (req, res) => { res.send("OK"); });
```

My test file follows the sample [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/74ff63e0e11a8ebea27b6f65826852d7b0e25220/functions/helloworld/helloworldHttp/test/sample.unit.http.test.js):

```js
// index.spec.js
const {getFunction} = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework/testing');
require('../../');

describe("HelloTests", () => {
  test("is testable", () => {

  });
});
```

When I run `jest` I get the following error:

`Cannot find module '@google-cloud/functions-framework/testing' from 'spec/unit/index.spec.js'`

Some additional observations:

1. If I put that import statement into `index.js` and run the application, it imports just fine.
2. If I comment out the import statement from `index.spec.js` but leave it in `index.js` and run `jest`, I get the same error for the import in `index.js`.

This leads me to assume that Jest is not properly handling submodules. I've never worked with submodules like this before (that I can remember), so I'm at a complete loss. I did some digging and this is from the `functions-framework` node module's `package.js`:

```json
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "types": "./build/src/index.d.ts",
      "default": "./build/src/index.js"
    },
    "./testing": {
      "types": "./build/src/testing.d.ts",
      "default": "./build/src/testing.js"
    }
  },
```

No idea if this is relevant but wanted to include it in case it's useful.

Any idea why I'm getting this error and/or how to resolve it without switching to ESM?

Update: I switched to ESM and get the exact same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This apparently got fixed earlier this year:

Issue: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9771

Initial Release: https://github.com/facebook/jest/releases/tag/v28.0.0-alpha.3

I had copied an older (but still fairly recent!) package.json that was stuck on v27 so it wasn't picking up the latest library. Did a clean install and confirmed no further issue with at least `v29.3.1`.

Rookie mistake.